# limit mysql database changes to no more than one every hour

Tags: mysql

I would like to have a button, that when clicked, would check to see if a database value was changed within the last 60 minutes.  If it was, just read the value.  But if it has been 60 minutes or longer, the value will change and then the 60 minute timer starts again.

Is there some kind of timer for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing built in to MySQL. Just keep track of the update time in a separate, 1-row table.

Comment: Thanks, I guess I'll use timediff, but I'm wondering if it's practical to use it every page load.